# How can I merge a single column from one file to another file

Tags: r, merge

```
A

phy     44
chem    46  
maths   44  
biol    42
his     38
comm    40


B
Name    RaK
Phy     45
chem    43
maths   41
His     38
Comm    48
geo     49
```

Expected output

```
            RaK
phy     44  45
chem    46  43
maths   44  41
biol    42   0
his     38  38
comm    40  48
```

I need something like `join(-a1 a,b)`. Is it possible to do it with R?
The first file doesn't have column headers.

Comment: Read in the files, add the column names (`names(A) <- c("Name", "col1")`), then use `merge`.

Comment: @lmo You could answer with that, `read.table(header = FALSE, text = [above])` etc. Btw, note that they have 0s for unmatched elements in A and omit unmatched elements of B.

Answer (score 2):

Read in the data:

```
A <- read.table(text="phy     44
chem    46  
maths   44  
biol    42
his     38
comm    40", as.is=TRUE)

B <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="Name    RaK
phy    45
chem    43
maths   41
his     38
comm    48
geo     49", as.is=TRUE)
```

The as.is=TRUE argument keeps the Name column as character rather than converting to factor. This is preferred when merging two different data.frames. Now, add column names to A.

```
names(A) <- c("Name", "col1")
```

Perform the merge, keeping all of the rows in A, regardless of whether B has such a row. Because both data.frames have a name in common, it is not necessary to add a by statement, though this is probably better practice.

```
dat <- merge(A, B, all.x=TRUE)
```

This returns

```
dat
   Name col1 RaK
1  biol   42  NA
2  chem   46  43
3  comm   40  48
4   his   38  38
5 maths   44  41
6   phy   44  45
```

Notice that the first value of Rak is missing (NA). To replace this with 0, you can use

```
dat$RaK[is.na(dat$RaK)] <- 0
```

and it is done.

```
dat
   Name col1 RaK
1  biol   42   0
2  chem   46  43
3  comm   40  48
4   his   38  38
5 maths   44  41
6   phy   44  45
```

Answer (score 2):

The OP has requested to join or merge *all* rows of file `A` with file `B` so that the expected result contains `biol` (from `A`) but not `geo` (from `B`).

In addition, the `Name` column of `B` is partially in title case whereas the corresponding column of `A` is in lower case.

It is assumed that the data of `A` are stored in a csv file called `"A.csv"` where the first row of `A.csv` is empty (blank). Likewise for `B` but here the first row constains the column headers.

With `data.table` this can be done using a "one-liner":

```
library(data.table)
# read B, convert Name column to lower case
fread("B.csv")[, Name := tolower(Name)][
  # read A and right join = all rows of A, only matching rows of B
  fread("A.csv"), on = c("Name" = "V1")][
    # replace NA by 0 
    is.na(RaK), RaK := 0L][]
```

> ```
>     Name RaK V2
> 1:   phy  45 44
> 2:  chem  43 46
> 3: maths  41 44
> 4:  biol   0 42
> 5:   his  38 38
> 6:  comm  48 40
> ```

`fread()` is `data.table`'s own, faster version of `read.table()`.

#### Data

For the sake of reproducibility, here are `A` and `B` *after* the calls to `fread()`:

```
A <- structure(list(V1 = c("phy", "chem", "maths", "biol", "his", 
"comm"), V2 = c(44L, 46L, 44L, 42L, 38L, 40L)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

B <- structure(list(Name = c("phy", "chem", "maths", "his", "comm", 
"geo"), RaK = c(45L, 43L, 41L, 38L, 48L, 49L)), .Names = c("Name", 
"RaK"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```